# Importing file data to a list from a function

Tags: python, file, list, function

I have a requirement to create repeating config files using the IP and hostnames of some servers. This data is contained in a large list similar to the mock data included;

```
192.168.0.1 -   data    info    hosta
192.168.0.2 -   data    info    hostb
192.168.0.3 -   data    info    hostc
192.168.0.4 -   data    info    hostb
```

This data contains arbitrary information that I don't want, such as the following items, '

```
-   data    info    '
```

I had the idea that I could read the split data into a list.
Then I would be able to loop over the list specifying only each numbered element within the list to be displayed, leaving only;

```
192.168.0.1
192.168.0.2
...
```

This would then be placed into a new list containing only the IP addresses.

I created a function that would read the the file into a list

```
def importlines():
    mf = open('C:\\scripts\\nagios\\filename.txt','r')
    lines = mf.read().split()
    print(lines)
mf.close()

#the data is read in correctly
#I then attempted to create a blank list
hosts = []

#then append the output from the function call to the list
hosts.append(importlines())
```

However this results in 'None', if I execute hosts.append(importlines()) once again I'm met with None,None. So it's it seems to be appending an elememt containing nothing into the list. I've tried executing hosts.append(print(importlines())) however I have the same issue.

As you can tell I'm what you might describe as an accidental sysadmin and have no experience in this. I'm also aware of the issue that this will create one large list, in my head I believe I require a list containing a list of each line. Am I off the mark here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting the whole file, not each line. Moreover, your function only *prints*, it doesn't actually use `return` to return the result to the caller.

```
def importlines():
    with open('C:/scripts/nagios/filename.txt') as mf:
        return [l.split()[0] for l in mf]
```

would return *only* a list of ip addresses. You can assign the result directly to `hosts`:

```
hosts = importlines()
```

Your own code did not return anything in `importlines()`, and the default return values for a python function is `None`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You have to return something from the function. The print() statement doesn't return anything.
Try something like this:

```
def importlines():
    toRet = []
    mf = open('C:\\scripts\\nagios\\filename.txt','r')
    lines = mf.read().split()
    for line in lines:
        toRet.append(line[0])
    return toRet
```

Comment: `.split()` splits on *all* whitespace, so `lines` will be a list of `['192.168.0.1', '-', 'data', 'info', 'hosta', '192.168.0.2', '-', 'data', 'info', 'hosta', ...]` values. Your function will return `['1', '-', 'd', 'i', 'h', '1', '-', 'd', ...]`, i.e. the first character of every non-whitespace series of characters in the file.